# NoMethodError: undefined method and for #ActiveRecord::Relation []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, where-clause

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to write a where clause with an AND to only return results subject to two conditions.  I tried this

```
  new_orders = Order
    .joins(:line_items => { :shipping => :vendor })
    .where.not(
      :vendors => { :id => vendor_ids }
    )
  ).and( 
    Order.joins(:line_items).where(:holding => nil)
  )
```

but am getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method and for #ActiveRecord::Relation [].  Did you mean?  any?" error.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `and` method available for an `ActiveRecord Relation`. There is only an [`or`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions) method available.

For your query, I think this should also work

```
new_orders = Order.joins(:line_items => { :shipping => :vendor })
                  .where.not(:vendors => { :id => vendor_ids })
                  .where(:holding => nil)
```